# Why does pprint to a writer truncate the output?

Tags: clojure

The following snippter:

```
(binding [*out* (writer "foo.txt")]
  (pprint models))
```

Will truncate the output at exactly 208Kb.
However the following:

```
(spit "foo.txt"
      (with-out-str
        (pprint models)))
```

Works fine and doesn't truncate the output.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sound like a buffer flush issue, try this:

```
(binding [*out* (writer "foo.txt")]
  (pprint models)
  (flush))
```

`flush` will flush the output stream buffers.